# AWT - printDialog(aset) vs. printDialog()

Tags: java, printing, awt

When the user hits OK in the `PrintDialog` - This code works

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
if (pjob.printDialog(aset)) {
   try {
       pjob.print(aset);     
   }
```

When the user hits OK in the `PrintDialog` - This code does not work

```
if (pjob.printDialog()) {
   try {
       pjob.print();     
   }
```

But with the first one it seems like it never gets in to the print method

```
 public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat format, int index) throws PrinterException {
    System.out.println("Print\n");
    etc...
```

The print never gets displayed.

Comment: It is great the snippets showed what you `try`d.  What did you `catch`?  Call `printStackTrace()` on whatever was caught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses a native printer dialog

```
if (pjob.printDialog()) {
   try {
      pjob.print();     
}
```

This one uses a cross platform printer dialog

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
if (pjob.printDialog(aset)) {
   try {
      pjob.print(aset);     
   }
```

Where I thought the code was never getting in the print Method was wrong.  I was looking in the wrong class to test the code.